# Кнопки социальных иконок на сайте

Tags: javascript, html

У кого-нибудь был опыт внедрения соц. иконок на сайт в родительской категории, чтобы заголовок, картинка и url брались для ребенка этой категории, например для facebook. Или не стоит пытаться. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Ничего не понятно

Comment: Иконки соц. сетей должны находиться только на определенной странице или можно их поставить и настроить на родительской странице-категории. Но чтобы ссылки вели на ребенка?

Comment: Иконки соц. сетей могут находится где угодно, и ссылаться куда угодно (даже на внешний сайт). А соц-сети берут заголовок, описание и картинку из мета информации страницы, которую они зашарили.